# How to automatically enable VPN for a Flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I live in syria and firebase does not work here. So when i need to use firebase, i use a vpn. But when the users use my app, i can not tell them to use vpn to see my app. Is there any way to make that's  work automatically on android and ios?

Comment: Well, if your apps Is only based in Syria, you should find another solution instead of firebase. One solution that works in Iran so should be fine even in Syria is http://docs.parseplatform.org

Comment: thank you for reply and parse work like firebase to store images and title ..?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I've never used it, but it's worth a try!